# Understanding / learning how to work with quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

When I try to work with quotient spaces in topology, I find myself stuck and confused.
I always find that the definition of a quotient space:
$$ \tau_{X / \sim}  = \{ V \subseteq X /\sim \, \mid q^{-1}(V) \ \text{is open on} \, X \}$$
Is not really comfortable to use. The definition and the map look so "clumsy", I feel like it's difficult to find open or closed sets in such a space. 
I also had the same problem with product space, but I eventually figured it out by understanding how neighborhoods behave in such spaces. However, in quotient spaces, we don't even have a basis to work with! 
I think I am missing something crucial with how to work with such spaces. If anybody has a source, or perhaps tips/tricks on how to work with quotient spaces, It'll really help. 
Thanks to all who respond!

Comment: Intuitively, the quotient space $X/\sim$ is the space obtained by gluing points in $X$. Most elementary examples of quotient space (with small dimension) can be visualized this way, except the projective plane. Open sets in $X/\sim$ are sort-of given by merging open sets in $X$. If you want some practice, you should work with some rather peculiar space, like the line with double origins. I am not a topologist, so I don't think I can give any more advice than that

Comment: While I do understand the idea behind quotient spaces, it appears that the execution is not pleasant. For example, I looked at the proof of how the quotient space $[a,b] / \{ a, b \} $ is homeomorphic to the unit circle, and it looked so clumsy considering it an easy concept to understand. I always think that maybe there's a more "natural" way of approaching this or a more ideal way to work on those spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I think most algebraic topologists would agree that such definitions are clumsy and not fun to work with, which is precisely why the categorical point of view is lauded. Quotients $X/\sim$ are characterized by a certain universal property: if $g:X \to Y$ is a continuous map such that $a \sim b$ implies $g(a)=g(b)$, then $g$ *uniquely* factors through the quotient map $q:X \to X/ \sim$.

In many cases (but perhaps not all) this universal property suffices to prove most things we need to prove about quotient spaces.

If you want to build some intuition as to the set-theoretic definition you've provided, I would recommend thinking of some simple examples. Consider $[0,1]$ with the endpoints identified. Verify that the quotient topology on this quotient space is consistent with the usual topology on $S^1$.

Comment: It is important that the factorization is unique. This property suffices to prove everything about quotient spaces since it completely characterizes the quotient space.

Comment: @QiZhu Edited, thanks

Comment: That is interesting. How for example this property helps?

Comment: hello, are you online?